# How to change text inside JQuery knob

Tags: jquery, text, input, font-size, jquery-knob

I want to change the text of JQuery Knob. For example I have a rate 23% consumed I want to put 23% on row and consumed in new row inside the circle. In other word, I want to add (consumed) under the percentage in different style (The font size of rate 16px and consumed 12px)

Comment: I need solution for this issue

Comment: I have jquery plugin which is draw circular progress bar 
http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/ . I want to add the percentage inside the circular progress in addition to text under the percentage.for example i have $100 in credit i consumed $10 it must be print 10% consumed 10% on row and consumed in other. H ow I can edit on the knob jquery plugin to accept this changes.

Comment: Can you update a screenshot for your requirement, that to see how you need to showcase.

Answer (score 0):

Add This to your knob options

```
format : function (value) {
    return value + '%';
}
```

Comment: hey man i want to something like that (value %)  with writing under this value (consumed) word (23% / Consumed)

Answer (score 0):

if you display % in your knob slider :

change line `format:function(v){return v}` to `format:function(v){return v + "%"}`

*above line must be in jquery.knob.min.js*